# how to give condition to loop through a variable containing data from different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following four variables in my controller index action which are retrieving data from different models and i have joined them as follows:

```
@forum = Forum.where(:user_id => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@poll=Poll.where(:created_by => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@article = Article.where(:user_id => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@jobpost = Jobplacement.where(:user_id => @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
@post =  @article + @jobpost + @forum + @poll
```

**In the view i wanted to loop through @post so i wrote -  @post.reverse.each do | post| but the problem is this post contains data from 4 different models and forum ,article,jobpost is having :user_id column whereas poll is having created_by as the column name for user_id field.because of this m getting the error undefined method `user_id' for # in following lines**

```
- if User.find(post.user_id).basic_info or User.find(post.created_by).basic_info
  - if User.find(post.user_id).basic_info.profilephoto?
    = image_tag User.find(post.user_id).basic_info.profilephoto.url(:thumb)
```

**how can i give condition like**

```
- if User.find(post.user_id).basic_info or User.find(post.created_by).basic_info
```

or

```
- if User.find(post.user_id or post.created_by).basic_info
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a messy thing to be doing.

but something like this should work:

```
user_id = post.user_id || post.created_by
if User.find(user_id).basic_info
```

BUT, you really shouldn't be doing database calls from a loop in your view.
It would be cleaner to do all the data collection in the controller and models.

Comment: no this is not working.m getting the same error as undefined method `user_id' for #<Poll:0xb689801c>

Comment: ok, you could try 
    user_id = post.respond_to?(:user_id) ? post.user_id : post.created_by

Comment: sorry, i should've specified that that line should replace the user_id = ... line of the answer i gave. If you still see the error, then you'll have to paste the whole file and error stack trace so we have a better idea of what we are working with.